# adding,saving data without refresh using jquery

Tags: jquery

can anybody give me a link or a sample of application of adding,saving data without refresh using jquery and .net technology

Comment: yup but i can't find a better solution.maybe someone have it

Answer (score 3):

[Let me Google this for You !](http://tinyurl.com/3yz7wym)

Comment: +1 for the cool "Let me Google this for You site" One new Bookmark for me